# Draw Line in View using Vector (in Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, vector

I'm trying to draw a line, I managed to do it before but the first point somehow was always 0, 0. Now my logic is, there are two Vectors, one to store each point that is clicked, and another to store the Line, which is made by two points clicked by the user. I do the verifications to see if the Vector is not empty and only then I draw the line. I don't really know what's going on, I've tried everything, hope some of you can help, I'm in real need. Thank you.
Here it goes the code from MyView.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MyView extends View {
    Paint paint = null;
    int figure;
    int lados_poly;
    int cor;
    int deletar;
    int CursorX, CursorY;
    int nrCliques;

    Vector<Ponto2D> ptsReta = new Vector<Ponto2D>();
    Vector<Reta> guardaRetas = new Vector<Reta>();

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        figure = 0;
        cor = 0;
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        figure = 0;
        cor = 0;
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        paint = new Paint();
        figure = 0;
        cor = 0;
    }


    public void clickEcra() {
        setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        CursorX = (int)event.getX();
                        CursorY = (int)event.getY();

                        if (figure == 2){
                            Ponto2D ptReta = new Ponto2D();
                            ptReta.x = CursorX;
                            ptReta.y = CursorY;
                            ptsReta.add(ptReta);
                            if (ptsReta.size()> 0) {
                                for (int c = 0; c < ptsReta.size(); c++)
                                System.out.println("ptRetaX: " + ptsReta.get(c).x + " ptRetaY: " + ptsReta.get(c).y + " size " + ptsReta.size());
                            }
                            invalidate();
                        }

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        clickEcra();

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F1E0"));
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#3F5866"));

        //cores
        if (cor == 1) {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#393E46"));
        } else if (cor == 2){
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00ADB5"));
        } else if (cor == 3) {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F8B500"));
        } else if (cor == 4) {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FC3C3C"));
        }


        if (figure == 2) {
            if (ptsReta.size() >= 2) {
                for (int b = 0; b < ptsReta.size(); b = b + 2) {
                    Reta retinha = new Reta(ptsReta.get(b), ptsReta.get(b + 1));
                    guardaRetas.add(retinha);
                    System.out.println("pts: " + ptsReta.get(b) + ptsReta.get(b + 1));
                }
            }

            if (guardaRetas.size() > 0) {
                for (int r = 0; r < guardaRetas.size(); r++) {
                    canvas.drawLine(guardaRetas.get(r).pinicial.x, guardaRetas.get(r).pinicial.y, guardaRetas.get(r).pfinal.x, guardaRetas.get(r).pfinal.y, paint);
                }
            }
        }

        //clear canvas
        if (deletar == 2){
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F1E0"));
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            nrCliques = 0;
            ptsCirc.removeAllElements();
            ptsReta.removeAllElements();
        }
    }


    public void setfigure(int a) {
        this.figure = a;
    }

    public void Cor1_mudar(int text_cor) {
        this.cor = text_cor;
    }

    public void Resetar(int delete){
        this.deletar = delete;
    }
}
```

And now the code from Line.java:

```
public class Reta {
    Ponto2D pinicial;
    Ponto2D pfinal;

    public Reta(){
        pinicial = new Ponto2D();
        pfinal = new Ponto2D();
    }

    public Reta(Ponto2D a, Ponto2D b) {
        pinicial = a;
        pfinal = b;
    }
}
```

**Update:** It draws one line, and when I try to do another one, on the third click, it closes and I need to draw multiple lines in my canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This were my changes, the following inside onDraw() method:

```
    if (figure == 2) {
        if (ptsReta.size() %2 == 0) {
            for (int b = 0; b < ptsReta.size(); b = b + 2) {
                Reta retinha = new Reta(ptsReta.get(b), ptsReta.get(b + 1));
                guardaRetas.add(retinha);
            }

            if (guardaRetas.size() > 0) {
                for (int r = 0; r < guardaRetas.size(); r++) {
                    canvas.drawLine(guardaRetas.get(r).pinicial.x, guardaRetas.get(r).pinicial.y, guardaRetas.get(r).pfinal.x, guardaRetas.get(r).pfinal.y, paint);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this ones inside the click method:

```
public void clickEcra() {
    setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    CursorX = (int)event.getX();
                    CursorY = (int)event.getY();

                    if (figure == 2){
                        Ponto2D ptReta = new Ponto2D();
                        ptReta.x = CursorX;
                        ptReta.y = CursorY;
                        ptsReta.add(ptReta);
                        invalidate();
                    }

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```